# How to import existing *.sql files in PostgreSQL 8.4?

Tags: postgresql, import

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4, and I have some *.sql files to import into a database.  How can I do so?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

in command line first reach the directory where psql is present then write commands like this:

```
psql [database name] [username]
```

and then press enter psql asks for password give the user password:

then write

```
> \i [full path and file name with extension]
```

then press enter insertion done.

Comment: I use this too. And it works. But, I change the supplied SQL statements. Previously the existing *.sql didn't use any character ; as the termination of a line. And I also must remove the GO. Do you t hink the sql script is not a psql script?

Comment: I tried to use \i [full path with extension] but I get the error message .sql no such file or directory. 
Could you please upload an example. Thanks.

Comment: If \i says no such file then it did not find a file at that position. It is best to give the absolute URL. For me on Windows, this commandline worked:     \i /tmp/robert/test.sql   of course you must have valid SQL commands in that file.

Answer (score 160):

From the command line:

```
psql -f 1.sql
psql -f 2.sql
```

From the `psql` prompt:

```
\i 1.sql
\i 2.sql
```

Note that you may need to import the files in a specific order (for example: data definition before data manipulation).  If you've got `bash` shell (GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, Cygwin) **and the files may be imported in the alphabetical order**, you may use this command:

```
for f in *.sql ; do psql -f $f ; done
```

Here's the documentation of the `psql` application (thanks, Frank): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: @moon Maybe you don't have access rights to the SQL files?  What operating system are you on?

Comment: @moon It's the password associated with your PostgreSQL user (the user-pass pair is stored in PostgreSQL).

Comment: @moon I suggest that you split your problem into three stages: 1) make sure that you can get `psql` running. 2) make sure your user has the necessary write privileges, such as: `CREATE`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc. 3) import the SQL files.  As far as I understand, you're at stage 1 now.

Comment: @Bolo: Would you put the three stages into the answer?

Comment: @Bolo , As you mentioned I'm now in third steps. but how I can import .sql file from my local machine. I tried  \i [full path with extension] but I get the error message .sql no such file or directory. Could you please give an example.

Comment: Okay, it`s working. How to update the new version of file
to the same database? So I have changed the first version of file
and now I would like to make this changes also in database from file.
Is it possible to do it exaclty the same way?
psql -f 1.sql
e.g. 1.sql has the same name but include changes inside.

Answer (score 40):

Well, the shortest way I know of, is following:

```
psql -U {user_name} -d {database_name} -f {file_path} -h {host_name}
```

**database_name:** Which database should you insert your file data in.

**file_path:** Absolute path to the file through which you want to perform the importing.

**host_name:** The name of the host. For development purposes, it is mostly `localhost`.

Upon entering this command in console, you will be prompted to enter your password.

Answer (score 27):

Be careful with "/" and "\". Even on Windows the command should be in the form:

```
\i c:/1.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Always preferred using a [connection service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgservice.html) (lookup/google 'psql connection service file')

Then simply:

```
psql service={yourservicename} < {myfile.sql}
```

Where `yourservicename` is a section name from the service file.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Puh7.png)

use following command :-

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin>psql -U username -d databasename -f D:\file.sql