# Import MySQL dump to Postres database using Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Hi I got a MySQL database dump, it's a `sql` file. Is there a way to import it to Postgres database using ruby? I know that there is a command like `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("path/to/file"))` but it fails, because of different databases. The main problem is to convert somehow sql file, to be a Postres format. Is it even possible using only Ruby On Rails?

Comment: Are you tried to use [--compatible=name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible) command line argument?

Comment: The problem is that I didn't even create this dump. I just got a sql file which I need to import to postgres database. I don't have acces to MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out pgloader? 
http://pgloader.io/
It's really easy to use and has helped me lots.

Or I'll refer to this question;
[How to import existing *.sql files in PostgreSQL 8.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393961/how-to-import-existing-sql-files-in-postgresql-8-4)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [mysql2postgres](https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres). I have used it more than 5 years ago but seems like it supported yet.