# Entering a .sql file into a new postgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I am having troubles getting started with psql. I can login using the script below

```
myusername@ubuntu:~/Desktop/dbscripts$ sudo su - postgres
postgres@ubuntu:~$
```

But, once here, I cannot figure out how to find my .sql file. 
I tried the options supplied by Bolo here: 
[How to import existing *.sql files in PostgreSQL 8.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393961/how-to-import-existing-sql-files-in-postgresql-8-4)
But they only give

```
myusername@ubuntu:~/Desktop/dbscripts$ psql -U root -d first -f myscript.sql
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "root"
```

and

```
myusername@ubuntu:~/Desktop/dbscripts$ psql -f myscript.sqlp
sql: FATAL:  role "myusername" does not exist
```

and

```
myusername@ubuntu:~/Desktop/dbscripts$ sudo su - postgres
postgres@ubuntu:~$ \i myscript.sql
The program 'i' is currently not installed. To run 'i' please ask your administrator to install the package 'iprint'
```

Comment: This can be handled from any of the above options you tried. In which path do you have myscript.sql? After you do su - postgres, give the full path . So it will be psql -d first -f <pathtosqlfile>/myscript.sql.   psql -U root will not work unless you  have a user root in the database. Try psql -U postgres.  You can do "\i sqlscript" at psql prompt, not at linux command prompt as you have done.  The error you are getting "role "myusername" does not exist" can be avoided either by using -U postgres (or any other db user) or by setting the PGUSER environment variable.

Comment: Thank you @jayadevan. The myscript.sql is in the ~/Desktop/dbscripts folder, but I can't find where my desktop folder is when I get into the postges@ubuntu prompt.

Comment: Nevermind. I just went down all the way to root and worked my way back up. Give me a minute to try your suggestions.

Comment: That got me going on the right track and works. Thank you for the very complete answer. If you make it into a Answer I will accept it.

Comment: Done. Posted it as answer.

Comment: `-U` specifies the **database** user to be used by `psql` so you should use `psql -U postgres`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be handled from any of the above options you tried. In which path do you have myscript.sql? After you do `su - postgres`, give the full path . So it will be `psql -d first -f <pathtosqlfile>/myscript.sql`. `psql -U root` will not work unless you have a user root in the database. Try `psql -U postgres`. You can do `\i sqlscript` at psql prompt, not at linux command prompt as you have done. The error you are getting "role "myusername" does not exist" can be avoided either by using -U postgres (or any other db user) or by setting the PGUSER environment variable.